# Docker image with ZK + OKHttp3 throws error

Tags: java, docker, zk, okhttp

I have a very big problem with Docker and ZK images. This does not happens locally on my machine but when i run on docker it throws me this error : 
[Error here](https://postimg.cc/image/uq8dyvt87/)

Docker file:

```
FROM java:8-jre
ADD target/my_file.jar my_file.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","my_file.jar"]
```

I bulid by typing

- 1.mvn clean package
- 2.docker build -t my_image .
- 3.sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 assets

Then it throws me the error like in the photo.

Please help me because i cant find anything.

```
Error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.net.NetProperties
        at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$1.run(DefaultProxySelector.java:94) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$1.run(DefaultProxySelector.java:92) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.<clinit>(DefaultProxySelector.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.ProxySelector.<clinit>(ProxySelector.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:478) ~[okhttp-3.9.1.jar!/:na]
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:226) ~[okhttp-3.9.1.jar!/:na]
        at zk.springboot.API.ApiService.<init>(ApiService.java:35) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
        at zk.springboot.MVCModel.NewAssetModel.<init>(NewAssetModel.java:55) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractUiFactory.newComposer(AbstractUiFactory.java:172) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractUiFactory.newComposer(AbstractUiFactory.java:184) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.Utils.newComposer(Utils.java:91) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposer(ComponentInfo.java:360) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.toComposers(ComponentInfo.java:330) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.resolveComposer(ComponentInfo.java:318) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:896) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:889) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:776) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:836) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:794) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:740) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:461) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:369) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.ZumlExtendlet.process(ZumlExtendlet.java:137) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.ZumlExtendlet.service(ZumlExtendlet.java:108) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web0(ClassWebResource.java:605) ~[zweb-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.web(ClassWebResource.java:592) ~[zweb-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.web.util.resource.ClassWebResource.service(ClassWebResource.java:272) ~[zweb-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:424) ~[zk-8.5.0-Eval.jar!/:8.5.0]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar!/:8.5.29]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please include your error in your post rather than link to an outside resource.  Also, that link doesn't work.

Comment: Hey nuni, I would love to help you, but as mentioned above I need more information for this. Can please provide your java code, your dockerfile, the commands your ran as well as the error code within the container.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Edited now. Hope is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Interestingly enough also when using ZK running in Docker, but with Apache Httpclient (version 4.5.6). It might be just a coincidence, though. I think that the particular version of JRE running the application (in the Docker container) does not have `sun.net.NetProperties`, for some reason.

I had this (throws the same exception for an HTTP call)

`FROM openjdk:8u162-jre`

I changed to this

`FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u181-b13-alpine-slim`

And it worked. I could not find `jdk8u181-b13-jre` on Docker, it would be interesting to now if this is JRE/JDK issue or just the version of JRE.

Comment: It was a problem with free/paid version. Thank you.